# SQL search configuration

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not very good at SQL and I have a simple zipcode finder that I created for my website.  The SQL is as follows:

```
$query = "select * from zipcodes2 where ZipCode like \"%$trimmed%\"
```

*\"%$trimmed%* of course is the actual zipcode the user enters in.  It works great but now I want to make it more advance by letting the user search for city or state and not just zipcode.  I already have the columns created and they are named "City" and "State".  What exactly should I put in the SQL line?  Will I have to change any other part of the code, specifically the \"%$trimmed%\ part?

Comment: If you are not letting users search for partial zipcodes, i.e. you are requiring 5 character input, you could use the equality operator (=) not "like". The entire table will have to be scanned if you use like with the %wildcard% on both sides of the search-term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a great approach but you can get close to what you want with this:

```
$query = "select * from zipcodes2 where ZipCode like '%$trimmed%' or (CONCAT(City, ',', State) = '$trimmed')"
```

But you must make sure the the user's response has no white space so it comes out as `Chicago,IL` and not anything like `Chicago, IL` or `Chicago , IL`.

You can do this by putting this before your query:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $trimmed );
```

Comment: This did not work. When I try it, it shows the first row in the table no matter what the query is.

Comment: That works but how do I get rid of the white space after the user enters it in?  I do not want to force the user to never put a white space.  That is not reliable.

Comment: I should add that this is what I have to trim the query: $var = @$_GET['q'] ;
  $trimmed = trim($var);

Comment: That last line in my answer will take out the whitespace. Just do it before you build the query. However, if you want reliability you should break this into multiple fields selected by the user. As I said, you can do what you want this way but it is not the best design.

Comment: I did place the last line before the query string but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Try this... str_replace(" ","",$trimmed). Also, I answered your original question. Mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
    select * 
    from zipcodes2 
    where 
    (
       ZipCode like '%$trimmed%'
       OR City like '%City%'
       OR State like '%State%'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish by modifying the SQL query to something like:

SELECT * FROM zipcodes2 WHERE ZipCode LIKE \"%$trimmed%\" OR (State = \"$state_vairable\" AND City = \"$city_variable\")

This of course depends on your end goal.  The above works if you're trying to match on explicit city/state combinations.

If you want people to be able to find the zipcodes of all the places called "townsville" in the us, remove the parenthesis and change the AND to an OR.

Comment: My end goal is to enable the user to pull up a listing by either searching by zipcode or by city/state combination.  They will have to enter city, state like so: Chicago, IL.  How do I do that?

Comment: In that case, the SELECT statement from above should do it:

Comment: Why do you have \"$state_vairable\"  and \"$city_variable\" ?  I only have one input line for the user to enter in the info.  It doesnt seem to work.  I have tried it with the same $trimmed in all three places.

Comment: You have two options.
1) Add other fields for city and state for folks to fill in, and shove those variables into the SQL statement.
2) Parse the input of the $trimmed variable to determine if they've supplied a zipcode or a city/state combination, break $trimmed into a $city and a $state if necessary and shove into the SQL statement.

Comment: How do I go about determining if they entered in either a zipcode or city/state combo?